# Reading Data from $.getJSON Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am trying to consume a REST API for which i am using the $.getJSON method.
I am getting the required JSON Output, but not in the method's output(in result variable) to process. Also the alert message is not coming. Its just blank output.
Please find the attached code and image(Containing the response output which i need in the Developer Tools of the browser)https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m2VQ.png

```
<body>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button onclick="callSAPRestService2()">Click me</button>
    <script>

         function callSAPRestService2() {
              $.getJSON('http://xxxx:8000/sap/bc/zrest_demo?sap-client=200',
                            function (result) {
                                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                            });
         }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: _I am getting the required JSON Output, but not in the method's output(in result variable) to process_. Then where you are getting _the required JSON Output_?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion.I have attached the image of the Debugging Session where i am getting the output. @GuruprasadRao

Comment: So that should be from `console.log` right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao No, its from the local stack on the right hand side(Chrome)

Comment: still confusing.. Could you please add a demo if possible? with some dummy working rest api url?

Comment: Thanks a Lot. $.get worked !!!!! @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Hi @GuruprasadRao, thank you for the explanation. Kindly, add it as an answer.

Comment: Am going to add this answer so that it will help others in future.. Please do accept it and up vote if possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically its because you have to `return Json` from your API `response` and then you can use `$.getJSON`. Since you haven't added your `API` code, I believe it isn't returning `JSON response`. If it is not `JSON response` then you can use `$.get` is fine.